# How to escape "@" and "(" character in password inside PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

How can I retrieve the "@" and "(" inside of the PowerShell script.

When I'm trying to `npm config get proxy` the proxy displayed is `http://username:ZA%40(testpassword@domain:8080/` but I want to display is `http://username:ZA@(testpassword@domain:8080/`

TEST: `git config --global http.proxy http://username:ZA%40%28testpassword@domain:8080 --replace-all`

I am trying to display the "@" by using `%40` and for "(" is `%28`.

I'm thinking if the reserved character "@" is in the side of "("

Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: Easiest way is probably to just quote the string, eg. pass the argument `'http://.../'` instead of `http://.../`

Comment: place it in single quotes.

Comment: If you just want to display what you get back from npm, try decoding it like: `$proxy = npm config get proxy` then `$string = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($proxy)`